# Nextjs 13 api route cannot be called from subpages

Tags: next.js13

I'm currently working on a nextjs 13 project with api routes
I have my api folder [my api folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw80u.png), and my Solution page and subpages which will call the api/product [my Solution folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSh4b.png), the page file in Solution work normally, however the subpage from Solution/[id] and Solution/[id]/[idcontent] will add the pathname whenever I refresh the page and call the api.

I try to add the current url as a global env, however I realized that I will have to change it whenever the code is deployed, is there a way to optimize it? or getting the current url without the pathname with code.
Here is my code
This cannot be called from subpages:

```js
let url = "api/new";

  const res = await fetch(
   
      url,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        searchField: searchField,
        role: role,
      }),
    },
  );
```

My current solution:

```js
 let url = "api/new";

  const res = await fetch(
    window.location.protocol +
      "//" +
      window.location.hostname +
      ":" +
      window.location.port +
      "/" +
      url,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        searchField: searchField,
        role: role,
      }),
    },
  );
```

I am looking for a better solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.